# Calling a function on each in Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps-api-3, pug, keystonejs

I'm trying to implement Google maps in a Jade template. Using KeystoneJS as a CMS, I have a number of "profiles" (basically people with their addresses) that I want to add to a map as markers.

```
block js
  script.
        var map;
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.0360272, 3.7359072),
              zoom: 8
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                mapOptions);

        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

block content
   .container
       script(src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<GOOGLE_API_KEY>&sensor=false')

     if data.profiles
        each profile in data.profiles
            #{new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(profile.address.geo[1], profile.address.geo[0]), map: map, title: profile.name.full})}

    div(id="map-canvas", style="width:100%; height:700px;")
```

The map shows correctly but when I add the 'each' code block I get an error "Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined".

How can I add a piece of js code that executes on 'each' in Jade?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're really close, the only problem is that the inside of the variable, i.e. `#{this_stuff}` is *all* executed in jade's context (which won't have the `google` object, as this is client-side).

It's a bit tricky because you're dealing with two completely different javascript environments here: **server side** and **client side**.

So you need to output server-side variables in your jade, into javascript code that will be executed client-side.

On a related note, you *can* use Jade variable syntax in script blocks, but can't do other things (like loops).

Firstly, let's clean it up so all your `script` tags are in the `js` block (which, assuming you're using the example KeystoneJS templates would be down the bottom of the `<body>` tag) and get those profiles being generated correctly:

```
block js
    script(src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<GOOGLE_API_KEY>&sensor=false')
    script.
        var map;
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.0360272, 3.7359072),
                zoom: 8
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                mapOptions);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialise);

    if data.profiles
        each profile in data.profiles
            script.
                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(#{profile.address.geo[1]}, #{profile.address.geo[0]}),
                    map: map,
                    title: "#{profile.name.full}"
                });

block content
   .container
        div(id="map-canvas", style="width:100%; height:700px;")
```

This is getting closer (and the Jade will generate what you're expecting now), but it won't work (yet) because you're potentially adding the markers to the map *before* the `initialize` function has run.

It's also not escaping the values, so things like a `"` character in the name would cause a syntax error.

A more robust way of doing it would be to populate a client-side array then loop over that *after* the map has been created. We'll also use `JSON.stringify` to make sure the values are escaped properly.

```
block js
    script(src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<GOOGLE_API_KEY>&sensor=false')
    script.
        var map,
            profiles = [];

        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.0360272, 3.7359072),
                zoom: 8
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                mapOptions);

            for (var i = 0; i < profiles.length; i++) {
                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(profiles[i].geo[1], profiles[i].geo[0]),
                    map: map,
                    title: profiles[i].name
                });
            }
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialise);

    if data.profiles
        each profile in data.profiles
            script.
                profiles.push({
                    geo: !{JSON.stringify(profile.address.geo)},
                    name: !{JSON.stringify(profile.name.full)}
                });

block content
   .container
        div(id="map-canvas", style="width:100%; height:700px;")
```

*Note the change to !{variable} so the JSON isn't escaped*

Finally, I'd recommend building up the `profiles` array in your route `.js` file for the view, rather than doing it in the jade template. It's a lot cleaner, and you won't end up with heaps of `<script>` tags in your page.

So your route would look something like this (I am assuming a fair bit to give you the idea, and using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org) to make the code neater than vanilla javascript)

```
var keystone = require('keystone'),
    _ = require('underscore');

exports = module.exports = function(req, res) {

    var view = new keystone.View(req, res),
        locals = res.locals;

    // Load the profiles
    view.query('profiles', keystone.list('Profile').model.find());

    // Create the array of profile markers
    view.on('render', function(next) {
        locals.profileMarkers = locals.profiles ? _.map(locals.profiles, function(profile) {
            return { geo: profile.address.geo, name: profile.name.full };
        }) : [];
        next();
    });

    // Render the view
    view.render('profiles');

}
```

Then in your view template:

```
block js
    script(src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<GOOGLE_API_KEY>&sensor=false')
    script.
        var profileMarkers = !{JSON.stringify(profileMarkers)},
            map;

        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.0360272, 3.7359072),
                zoom: 8
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                mapOptions);

            _.each(profileMarkers, function(profile) {
                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(profile.geo[1], profile.geo[0]),
                    map: map,
                    title: profile.name
                });
            });
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialise);

block content
   .container
        div(id="map-canvas", style="width:100%; height:700px;")
```

Comment: Slight change to your code:                         <code> view.on('render', function(next) {
        locals.profileMarkers = locals.profiles ? _.map(locals.profiles, function(profile) {
            return { geo: profile.address.geo, name: profile.name.full };
        }) : [];
    });  <code>                                                                    should include a call to next(), otherwise it's stuck rendering.

Answer (score 0):

> "Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined"

Cannot help with this, seems that google maps fail to initialize or something like that.

But I can tell you that if you want to execute JavaScript in your Jade template, you just need to start the line with a dash: `var x = Math.random()`

I think there is (another) error in the line which starts with `#{new google.maps.Maker...`.
This is not JS, it's Jade, and the result the the constructor would be used as HTML tag, I think you don't want that.

Here is an example, you can paste it into this online editor on http://jade-lang.com/demo/

```
- var ar = [1,2,3]
ul
  each item in ar
    - var x = Math.random()*item
    li= x
```

You can check out my gist for some Jade syntax hints: https://gist.github.com/timaschew/7543cf3d0c455f686784

Comment: While you're right about the dash to embed js in jade templates, he's trying to generate valid js code in the jade template which will be run client-side to create the google map and place the markers. So in this case (and inside the script. block) he's doing the right thing. The problem is that the whole #{new google.maps.Maker...} code is being evaluated as a jade variable, when only the values (geo, name) should be evaluated, and the rest is just text as far as jade is concerned.